# XDocument created with XElement has unwanted White spaces

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am Creating XDocument with Xelements

```
XDocument document = new XDocument(element);
```

And I tried removing unwanted nodes with

```
List<string> eNames = new List<string> { "Name", "Price", "Year", "Model"};
document.XPathSelectElements("s0:Customer/s0:Loan/s0:Vehicle/*", namespaceManager)
.Where(x => (!eNames.Contains(x.Name.LocalName)))
.Remove();
```

IT works fine but with unwanted white spaces. How to remove unwanted white spaces between nodes after removing?

Output looks like

```
     </Vehicle>

     <Vehicle>



        <Name>Toyota</Name>
        <Year>2012</Year>

        <Make>TOYOTA</Make>
        <Model>CAMRY L/LE/SE/XLE</Model>






























     </Vehicle>
```

Comment: what does your output XML look like?

Comment: How does your document look like before removing the elements?

Comment: It has nodes in the whitespaces now...since i removed nodes, its showing the blank spaces

Comment: Can you try `String.Replace('\n\n','\n')`

Comment: Can you post a more complete example? Without knowing what your `document` looks like or how you're getting the output, it's not possible to replicate the issue. I tested with my own document and it works fine. Please see here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
           XDocument document = new XDocument();
            foreach (XElement element in document.Elements())
            {
                element.Value = element.Value.Trim();
            }
```